# find the biggest possible number comprised of the digits of of a given number

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given a number N find the biggest possible number X that can be created from the given number digits.

Example: N=231 then X will be 321.

The restrictions are time complexity O(1)
and space complexity O(1).

I think this has to be done with counting sort.

Comment: I don't see how the algorithm can be any faster than O(n) since you have to at least read the input (length n). From there, you'd need an in-place sort to also avoid taking up more than O(1) memory.

Comment: Does having a ten-element array of integers count as "o(1) space complexity"?

Comment: Feels a lot like a homework assignment...

Comment: @Kevin yes because it is a constant, your asking for counting sort?

Comment: @bbill this is why i am stuck on this.

Comment: @DeadChex almost an interview qustion.

Comment: raven I'm pretty sure you can't do this faster than O(n) using the definition of n as length in digits and simple operations :)

Comment: Means O(1) space complexity that the memory usage is constant and independent from the input? You could just calculate a HashMap with all possible N's as keys and their corresponding value as value (or why not just an array), so you have also O(1) time complexity for getting the value. If maxN is not too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best I can do is O(1) space and O(log(N)) time. Pretty sure it's impossible to do any better because at the bare minimum you have to analyze each digit in the input, which is log(N) right there.

The short answer is, sort the digits of N in descending order.

Pseudocode:

1. Create an array of 10 integers, all initialized to zero.
2. iterate through each digit of N. increment the slot in the array that corresponds to each digit.
3. Iterate through the array. Add N instances of the character C to the beginning of the result string, where N is the number stored in slot number C in the array.

Sample Python implementation:

```
N = 231
slots = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
while N > 0:
    slots[N%10] += 1
    N = int(N / 10)

result = ""
for slot_idx in range(10):
    for i in range(slots[slot_idx]):
        result = str(slot_idx) + result

print result
```

Result:

321

Comment: this solution is the one i thought of as well. thank you for conforming that o(1) complexity cannot be reached.